# htaccess mod_rewrite directory to variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file.

I've found numerous tutorials about how to do the reverse of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically I need a solution to change directories to get variables.

So that this:

```
http://example.org/page-1
```

turns into

```
http://example.org/?link_id=page-1
```

I think I got a code that would do something almost to what I need, but I was getting redirect loops.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]*)$ index.php?link_id=page-$1
```

**Note**: I'm not sure that `index.php` is your `DirectoryIndex`. If it's not, you should change it according to your index file.